# CORS Issue: Redux not fetching data from Django API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, django-rest-framework, axios, cors

I'm currently working on a project where I have a frontend application running on **`http://localhost:3000`** and a backend API on **`http://localhost:8000`**. I'm encountering a CORS issue when trying to make requests from my frontend to the backend API.

Here's the error message I'm receiving in the browser's console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/list-accounts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I I want to retrieve account data from django and display it in a React component. I've set up a Redux store to manage the state of my application, and I'm using Redux Thunk for asynchronous actions.

This is the Redux action for fetching Account data:

```
export const fetchAccounts = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      try {
        dispatch(fetchAccountsRequest()); // Dispatch a request action
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/list-accounts`, {
          withCredentials: true, 
        });
        const accounts = response.data;
        dispatch(fetchAccountsSuccess(accounts)); 
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(fetchAccountsFailure(error)); 
      }
    };
  };

const fetchAccountsRequest = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FETCH_ACCOUNTS_REQUEST,
});

const fetchAccountsSuccess = (accounts: Account[]) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FETCH_ACCOUNTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: accounts,
});

const fetchAccountsFailure = (error: any) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FETCH_ACCOUNTS_FAILURE,
  payload: error,
});
```

```
export function CardWithAccounts() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const accounts = useAppSelector((state:RootState) => state.accounts.accounts)
  const loading = useAppSelector((state: RootState)=> state.accounts.loading)
  
    
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAccounts())
  }, [dispatch])

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
   
    return ( <div></div>)
```

In my component called **`CardWithAccounts`**, I'm using hooks to access the account data from the Redux store. My goal is to map through this data and render it in a card, displaying account details.

I've already tried several CORS configurations on the django backend, but I still can't seem to get rid of this error.

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1","localhost"]
```

Also this is my Redux dev tools logs:

[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FheBC.png)

[Log monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CryvS.png)

NOTE!:
I have other API calls in my app that work properly, this is the only request i get a CORS error.

Comment: And did you remember to actually add the cors app and middleware to your Django config? Because those CORS settings aren't going to do much without the `corsheaders` app and the `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` middleware. (and remember that CORS is based on origin, not host, you _need_ the port as well as the protocol and domain)

Comment: Yes i did, i just didnt want to include all the middleware in the question

Comment: Please include it in the question. If you're showing your CORS vars, also show that the cors requirements are in the settings.py file (with `...` placeholders for "you don't need to see the rest of this list" of course, but of course with the django common middleware  not removed because it's important to show where that is relative to your other middleware, since Python loads middlerware last to first). That said: take React out of the picture and use curl. What is the result? (and ideally put that in your post, too)

Answer (score 0):

GO with these settings of Django in **`settings.py`**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', # <-------- this
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <-------- this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'sales_company_app.get_user_instance.RequestMiddleware',
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # <-------- this
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",    # React (FrontEnd Url) # <-------- this
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*' # <-------- this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] # (Api Base Url) <-------- this (allow csrf_token) for doing whitelist
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a / on:

```
 try {
        dispatch(fetchAccountsRequest()); 
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/list-accounts`, {
          withCredentials: true, 
        });
```

Fix:

```
const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/list-accounts/`
```